# Using Spotify with the new Google Assistant SDK?

Tags: spotify, google-assistant-sdk

Is it possible? I can't figure out how. I can only find instructions detailing how to set up Spotify using the Google Home app.

Comment: It depends on what you want to do with Spotify? I'm not too familiar with the Google Assistant SDK, but if it supports HTTP requests you can call the [Spotify Web API](https://developer.spotify.com/web-api/). If the user has logged into their Spotify account on their Home device already, you'll be able to control playback on the device using the [Connect API Endpoints](https://developer.spotify.com/web-api/web-api-connect-endpoint-reference/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per the [release notes](https://developers.google.com/assistant/sdk/release-notes), playing music is not currently supported in the developer preview.

Comment: Why does Google Home have it then? Why don't we have all features as developers?

Comment: Commercial devices will be allowed to use Spotify and other media playback solutions. Non-commercial prototypes currently don't support it for complicated reasons, but we'll try to make it happen in the future.